# Is it possible to remap the “Hide Window” shortcut in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Is it possible to remap the “Hide Window” shortcut in Mac OS X? I know about the possibility to remap just about any shortcut in the System Preferences that are either built in or just available in a specific app.

The thing is that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is not being shown as a “built-in” shortcut. Also this shortcut is special in that it has a different name in the menu in every app in that it is called “Hide Appname.” That makes it impossible to generically add it manually to the shortcuts. Unless there was a way to use Regexps or there would be a magic constant like “Hide Appname.”

---

*The reason I’m asking this question is that I want to use CMD inside my Linux VMs as Meta key so that my tiling window manager has a sweet shortcut. Currently this works fine, unless I accidentally hide the Window.*